# Where do you put the dotcloud.yml file?

Tags: dotcloud

I have no idea what I'm doing -

Where do I put the dotcloud.yml file?

There isn't much help on this for people who don't knwo what they're doing. Insturcitons just say create the file.... where do you put it? In my pictures? In my documents? In a new folder called "pics of mj" on my desktop?

Comment: and then how do you upload that to dotcloud with the command line?

Answer (score 3):

The `dotcloud.yml` file will generally be located in the directory containing the code of the application that you want to deploy on dotCloud.

I would recommend to check the dotCloud tutorials, e.g. http://docs.dotcloud.com/firststeps/quickstart/ ; I think it will explain all you need to know :-)

If you are referring to a specific guide or tutorial, don't hesitate to mention which one—if it's a doc maintained by dotCloud, they will certainly update it!

Comment: Hi. Thanks. That tutorial doesn't indicate where the dotcloud.yml file goes... it simply says to create it then push the project. Where exactly on my computer do I put the dotcloud.yml file, and then how do I indicate the folder to push to dotcloud? Thanks

Comment: We've added an additional section to the dotCloud documentation which talks about the dotcloud.yml file in greater detail.  http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/build-file/

Answer (score 0):

Probably in the root of your app/project directory, that's where I have a config.yml in a Ruby project. You can see an example of an yml file in the repo linked below.

https://github.com/ramaze/ramaze

I'm unfortunately not familiar with that deployment platform? So I'm not sure what the zoom command would do in that prompt.

For ruby it looks like the deploy command is `dotcloud push [foldername]` in the prompt.

http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/ruby/

Answer (score 0):

There is a hint in the [dotcloud.yml docs](http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/build-file/#approot-specifying-the-root-directory-of-a-service), but you're right, we need to make the location more explicit.

The `dotcloud.yml` file must go at the root of your source tree.